# How can i export Orbeon form data into xml

Tags: xml, orbeon

I a looking at Orbeon Forms (PE) to enable my customers to complete configuration data for their system and i need to export that data into XML format to enable me to load that into our system.

How do I get the xml output for a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data entered in forms you create with Form Builder is captured by Orbeon Forms in XML documents. There are 3 ways for you to access this data:

1. By implementing a service to receive the data, and configuring Orbeon Forms to call that service when new data is submitted by users.
2. By calling a REST API provided by Orbeon Forms to pull data saved or submitted by users.
3. By accessing the database where Orbeon Forms stores the data saved or submitted.

For more on those techniques, see [Access form data](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/overview/accessing-data).